# Create SSRS .rdl report which should accept Dataset/DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Here i don't have any code to show,
But in my application,

```
=>I am consuming web service, which provides me `List<ClassName>` 
=>Convert that List<ClassName> into Dataset/DataTable.
=> Pass Dataset/DataTable into .rdl report.
```

So How can I Create SSRS .rdl report which should accept Dataset/DataTable passed using C# code?

Comment: sounds like you are looking to write a custom data processing extension for SSRS correct? This article should get you started. http://sqlmag.com/database-development/creating-custom-data-processing-extension

Comment: Would it not be easier, to process your data elsewhere i.e from web-service into the database and then create an RDL report using the database?